# Laravel 4 DB:raw() is unavailable when running outside of framework

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using the [illuminate/database component][1] from Laravel 4 through composer - and while it generally works well, the DB facade seems to be broken in this standalone version. This meant I was unable to use static functions such as DB::raw(). It seems like the DB facade is even included in the package, but it doesn't work with ::raw().

I'm trying to do something like this -

```
...->orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Capsule::raw()` is available, and is linked to the default connection's `raw()`.

Also, what I did is I created a class:

```
/**
 * @method static raw($value)
 * @method static array select($query, $bindings = [], $useReadPdo = true)
 * ...etc.
 */
class DB extends Manager
{
}
```

so that

1. You can use DB::raw().
2. IDE code completion works.

Answer (score 1):

I found a partial solution, but if anyone has any ideas that work better, I'm eager to hear them (it seems the [original Capsule package](https://github.com/philsturgeon/capsule) actually had support built in, maybe it was lost when it was merged, or maybe I'm using it incorrectly?)

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

$connection = Capsule::connection();

// You can now use $connection->raw() in place of DB::raw()
...->orderBy($connection->raw('RAND()'))
```